# Pass multiple parameters in a stored procedure to a QueryString Parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How can pass two SQL parameters in a stored procedure to a query string in the WHERE clause? The issue I'm having is in the @iField. If I remove that and replace with InfoID LIKE '%' + @iSearch + '%', it works, but I need to add the @iField.
`WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID AND @iField LIKE '%' + @iSearch + '%'`

Answer (score 1):

As far as you are allready using a procedure

```
Declare @Query nvarchar(max)
Select @Query=
'
Select * from dbo.Invoice
WHERE CustomerID = '+Cast(@CustomerID as Varchar(20)) 
+' AND ['+ @iField +'] LIKE ''%' + @iSearch + '%''
'

--Print @Query
Exec(@Query)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using your suggestion I'm getting an `Invalid column name ''+ @iField +''` error.

Comment: @g_shockTan just copying my post I get results print will show e.g. Select * from dbo.Invoice
WHERE CustomerID = 1 AND [BillNr] LIKE '%aus%'  Try with print instead of Exec, might be missing quotation ...

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL doesn't allow you to substiute variables for object names (it would be handy though, wouldnt' it). Two options really:

1) Use dynamic SQL  e.g. sp_executesql (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/306)

or

2) Use IF...ELSE e.g.

```
IF @iField = 'InfoId'
     SELECT ...
     WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID AND InfoId LIKE '%' + @iSearch + '%'
ELSE IF @iField = '<some other field>'
     SELECT ...
     WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID AND <some other field> LIKE '%' + @iSearch + '%'
etc.
```

Comment: Basically I would like to know if it's possible to write the WHERE clause as: `WHERE @iField LIKE '%' + @iSearch + '%'`.

Comment: No you can't substitue column names, table names, procedure names etc. with variable names unless you build a sql string and execute it dynamically as in (1) above.

Comment: Very interesting article. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are simply trying to limit the `like` operator to a specific column?

```
declare @yourTable table (i int, FirstName varchar(10), LastName varchar(10))
insert into @yourTable
    select 1, 'john', 'doe' union all
    select 2, 'jane', 'doe';


declare @iField varchar(10),
        @iSearch varchar(10);


select  @iField = 'FirstName',
        @iSearch = 'j'


select  *
from    @yourTable
where   (@iField = 'FirstName' and FirstName like '%' + @iSearch + '%') or
        (@iField = 'LastName' and LastName like '%' + @iSearch + '%')
```